# My script for Roblox wont work. Its supposed to close all other frames when the button is clicked

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

So it throws no errors. All of the frames are being referenced correctly. I am so confused and do not know how to fix it, I have been searching for examples and cannot find ANYTHING. Even ChatGPT couldnt make a working one.

```
local StarterGui = game:GetService("StarterGui")
local DonationGui = StarterGui:WaitForChild("GamepassesGUI").Box
local TutorialGui = StarterGui:WaitForChild("TutorialGUI").Box
local CashDropGui = StarterGui:WaitForChild("CashDropGui").MainFrame

local function checkGuiOpen(gui1, gui2, gui3)
     return gui1.Visible or gui2.Visible or gui3.Visible
end

local function closeAllGuis(gui1, gui2, gui3)
     gui1.Visible = false
     gui2.Visible = false
     gui3.Visible = false
end

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
if checkGuiOpen(DonationGui, TutorialGui, CashDropGui) then
     print("Other GUIs are open")
     closeAllGuis(DonationGui, TutorialGui, CashDropGui)
     if script.Parent.Parent.Box.Visible then
          script.Parent.Parent.Box.Visible = false
     else
          script.Parent.Parent.Box.Visible = true
     end
else
     if script.Parent.Parent.Box.Visible then
          script.Parent.Parent.Box.Visible = false
     else
          script.Parent.Parent.Box.Visible = true
          StarterGui.Currency.Frame.Visible = false
     end
end
end)
```

I rewrote it alot. Also, it is a LocalScript

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you getting StarterGUI if this is in a localscript? If I understand correctly, this is all you should have to do...

```
local DonationGui = --insert gui location in here example: script.Parent.Parent.Parent.DonationGui--
local TutorialGui = --insert gui location in here example: script.Parent.Parent.Parent.DonationGui--
local CashDropGui = --insert gui location in here example: script.Parent.Parent.Parent.DonationGui--

local function closeAllGuis(gui1, gui2, gui3)
     gui1.Visible = false
     gui2.Visible = false
     gui3.Visible = false
end

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
if DonationGui.Visible == true and TutorialGui.Visible == true and     CashDropGui.Visible == true then then
     print("Other GUIs are open")
     closeAllGuis(DonationGui, TutorialGui, CashDropGui)
     if script.Parent.Parent.Box.Visible == true then
          script.Parent.Parent.Box.Visible = false
     else
          script.Parent.Parent.Box.Visible = true
     end
else
 if script.Parent.Parent.Box.Visible == true then
      script.Parent.Parent.Box.Visible = false
 else
          script.Parent.Parent.Box.Visible = true
          StarterGui.Currency.Frame.Visible = false
     end
end
end)
```